# CSV file reading problem (not using CSV module), program not offering option for input where it should

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

**I need help with the first section of the program, where I am trying to create a condition which will** **only offer the user the option to input a province if the selected country has a province listed in the data file.** for example, if the user selects austria, which doesn't have any provinces listed, it should not offer that option. but if they select Australia, then it should prompt them for a province input.

I CANNOT USE the CSV module, as my course at Uni hasn't covered the module yet, and the professor would rather have us apply basic file reading concepts. I don't really need to anymore, as I got the main solution already.

An example of the data from this file is:

```
province                    | country    | 1/2/20 | 1/3/20 | 1/4/20|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
                            | Afghanistan|   0    |   1    |   2   |  
                            | Albania    |   0    |   0    |   1   |
Australian Capital Territory| Australia  |   0    |   3    |   5   |
New South Wales             | Australia  |   4    |   5    |   6   |
                            | Austria    |   0    |   3    |   4   |
```

(For reference, the data I need to use is :https://portland-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/msharma8-c_ad_cityu_edu_hk/ES7eUlPURzxOqTmRLmcxVEMBRGlLq6REGHx0hs_bNilPTw?e=6Ybsmc )

However, **my code just doesn't offer the input option for a province at all now.**

```py
with open('covid19.csv', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            # this next line is not working ffs ahhh, it doesnt seem to understand what i need
            if (country == line.split(',')[1]) and len(line.split(',')[0])>1:
                while True:
                    province = raw_input('input a province/district here: ')
                    if province.lower() in province_list:
                        break
```

I have also tried:

```py
if (country == line.split(',')[1]) and (line.split(',')[0]) != '':
```

For further reference, here is the entire chunk of code, which i've placed in a function:

```py
with open('covid19.csv', 'r') as f:
    country_list = []
    province_list = []
    date_list = ((f.readline().split(','))[4::])
    date_list = [date[0:-2] for date in date_list if date[-4:]=='2020'] # to put all the dates in the same format
    for line in f:
        #list of all countries and provinces
        province_list.append(line.split(',')[0].lower())
        country_list.append(line.split(',')[1].lower())

    while True:
        country = raw_input("input a country here: ")
        if country.lower() in country_list: 
            break
    with open('covid19.csv', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            # this line is not working ffs ahhh, it doesnt seem to understand
            if (country == line.split(',')[1]) and len(line.split(',')[0])>1:
                while True:
                    province = raw_input('input a province/district here: ')
                    if province.lower() in province_list:
                        break
    while True:
        date = raw_input('input a date in m/d/yy: ')
        if date in date_list:
            print 'You have selected the date:',date
            break
        else:
            print 'please enter a date in a valid format'
```

Comment: Show a relevant part of the CSV file (a few lines with and a few lines without province) as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: The link you gave does not work. Don't post data in external links, because they always break sooner or later. Copy a relevant section of the CSV file into the question.

Comment: Also, saying *"I cannot use the CSV module"* without explaining why is bold. The csv module is a core module, there is next to no reason why you should be unable to use it.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm sorry that the link doesn't work. I will try to fix it. I have posted a few lines of the data into the question. I cannot use the CSV module because my python course at uni is introductory, and we haven't covered the CSV module. The professor also feels that it's a better exercise in programming without the use of the module, though I'm sure it's much less efficient.

Comment: That's a good reason, probably the best of the very few that exist.

Comment: @Tomalak haha thanks, I wouldn't be doing it unless I had to.

Comment: The text shown in the question isn't part of a CSV file but more a graphical representation of the Excel table. Show a relevant part of the CSV file in the question.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I'm not sure what you mean. what other method is there to show a part of a file. I linked the file in the question, but how else would one show the file?

Comment: A CSV file is basically a text file and can be looked at and edited with a text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure your condition is evaluated correctly.

```
(country == line.split(',')[1]) and len(line.split(',')[0])>1
```

In Python, `and` has higher precedence than `>`, so the above line Python evaluates

```
(country == line.split(',')[1]) and len(line.split(',')[0])
```

and then determines whether the result is greater than 1.  In Python `True` and `False` equate to  `1` and `0` respectively, so the condition can never be true.

```
(country == line.split(',')[1]) and (len(line.split(',')[0]) > 1)
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you, while that does not work, for some reason, It is helpful.